# CSS (or JQuery) change color animation onclick

Tags: jquery, css, animation, colors

```
div
{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:red;
animation:myfirst 3s;
-moz-animation:myfirst 3s; /* Firefox */
-webkit-animation:myfirst 3s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}


@-webkit-keyframes myfirst /* Safari and Chrome */
{
0% {background:red;}
50% {background:#800000;}
100% {background:red;}
}
```

See [my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KHnBz/) (**DOES NOT WORK WITH IE OR OPERA**). Or see the CSS above.

Its a simple color animation that goes from red to dark red, and back to red. I need to make it such that when the button is clicked it will go from:

blue to #000066 and then back to blue.

I know one method is to create a new style sheet and switch stylesheets but,

(1) I'm not quite sure how to do that

and

(2) In the grand scheme of all of this I need to repeat this about 15 times with different colors, I would hate to have 15 different stylesheets for colors. Is there a JQuery or straight up javascript way of doing this?

Comment: No need to create a new stylesheet. Just create a different class for each color, and use jQuery to `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()`

Comment: I see what you mean. But how would I change the keyframes? They need to specify different colors

Comment: To indicate that Opera is:
-o-animation:myfirst 3s; 
-o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to create a new stylesheet. Just create a different class for each color, and use jQuery to [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass) and [`.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass):

```
function blueMe(){
  $('div').removeClass().addClass('blue');
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/KHnBz/6/

As you'll see in the CSS for that fiddle, you'll need to create new keyframes for each class.